# Using Drupal.settings.basePath in Modernizer / yepnope.js loads

Tags: 7, javascript

I am currently starting development of drupal sites on Acquia. Using git and working locally is a new workflow for me. When building locally and trying to utilize  Modernizr load / yepnope, my JS in my script.js file typically looks like this..

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
    test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
    nope: '/sitename/docroot/sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/polyfill.js'
    },
    ....
```

So that works locally on my machine, but when I commit my changes and push to my acquia development server the file path for the loaded scripts is incorrect, since it's not the same setup I guess.

http://mysite.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/mysite/docroot/sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/polyfill.js

It needs to be the below, without the mysite/docroot in the URL.

http://mysite.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/polyfill.js

So that brings me to Drupal.settings.basePath. If I print this out it gives me /mysite/docroot/ on my local setup. If I do it on the dev server, it would print out something different (probably just / ).

So me being the amateur assumed I could do something like this.. (forgive the poor sample, I know it can be done better)

```
var myroot = Drupal.settings.basePath

Modernizr.load([
{
test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
nope: myroot + 'sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/polyfill.js'
},
....
```

And this of course does not work. Just returns query1 is not defined.

So I am sure there are faults in many of my attempts to make this work.. so if anyone can suggest something to me, either workflow related or how to fix my setup / code, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried http://drupal.org/project/modernizr ?

Answer (score 1):

Your local environment seems to be misconfigured. If you're running apache with vhosts then your `VirtualHost` definition should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName whatever-you-choose-for-a-dev-domain.com
  DocumentRoot "/path/to/the/drupal/root/directory"
</VirtualHost>
```

Where the `DocumentRoot` should also include `/sitename/docroot`

Alternatively you may be able to edit .htaccess in the Drupal root directory to 
    RewriteBase /sitename/docroot
Which there should already be a commented definition of `RewriteBase` in there that you simply would uncomment. But I think the VirtualHost path would be the best one.

Comment: This is good info, as it does work if you are using a VirtualHost definition (I personally am, but I am taking into consideration that most people are not using a virtual host)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do

```
Modernizr.load([
    //first test need for polyfill
    {
        test: window.matchMedia,
        nope: (Drupal.settings.basePath + Drupal.settings.pathToTheme + "/js/polyfills/matchMediajs/matchMedia.js")
    },

    //and then load enquire
    (Drupal.settings.basePath + Drupal.settings.pathToTheme + '/js/enquirejs/dist/enquire.min.js')
]);
```

In my template.php I have the following in my _preprocess_page function:

```
drupal_add_js(array('pathToTheme' => path_to_theme()), 'setting');
```

Comment: I tried implementing this but have some issues.

Comment: Sigh. Silly 5 minute comment rule.

I tried implementing this but have some issues.

t Found) http://mysite.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/NaNsites/all/themes/my_theme/js/my.js

As you can see I get an NaN in the src url.

I am using the Omega theme so that means I have a preprocess-page.inc file that I added the drupal_add_js line to.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is a Drupal core bug in drupal_get_js(). The issue seems to be that the Drupal.settings information is actually inserted after all library, module, and theme JavaScript. According to the documentation of [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7), Drupal.settings should be added to the `JS_LIBRARY` group which has a weight of -100, whereas theme javascript has a weight of 100 and should go after the settings in the source order.

There is a one line patch at http://drupal.org/node/1710002 or you can try this workaround. The workaround assumes that your JavaScript will still work as expected in the footer (just before the `</body>`.

1. Remove the `scripts[] = js/myscript.js` from your theme's .info file.
2. In template.php, add the `drupal_add_js()` line to your existing `hook_preprocess_page()` or add this new function:

   ```
   /**
    * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
    */
   function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
     drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/myscript.js', array('scope' => 'footer'));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the APIs available inside the [Modernizr Drupal module](https://drupal.org/project/modernizr), it takes care of requesting the proper path for you. Here are some docs:

https://drupal.org/node/1913830